# Will there be any concern if I upgrade my current Wordpress Database server from Centos 7 Mariadb 5.5 to Centos 8 Mariadb 10.3?

Tags: database, upgrade

Currently I am using a dedicated web server connected via private network to a dedicated database server to run Wordpress. The database server is running on Centos 7 and mariadb 5.5.
I am considering to upgrade the web server to centos 8  and mariadb 10.3.

Questions:

1. Is it advisable to upgrade from mariadb 5.5 to mariadb 10.3 for wordpress? Would there be compatibility issues for existing Wordpress database? What are the areas of concern I should be aware of.
2. Is there a performance advantage for upgrading centos 7 mariadb 5.5 to centos 8 mariadb 10.3 for wordpress? Or I should stick to centos 7 mariadb 5.5 to avoid unnecessary trouble?

Comment: Keep in mind that questions need to be written so that they can be answered factually. I don't see a way to answer your very last question. We also have a 1 question per question policy. Most of this would be better asked on the ServerFault stack as it's mostly a dev ops question, not a WordPress question. However, if it's a separate server, why not duplicate it, perform the upgrade, and switch WP to the new upgraded DB server and see what the result is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is unaware of what kind of database server you're using, as long as it accepts MySQL flavour SQL, can be communicated with via the mysqli PHP extension, and supports the feature set of the minimum requirements, WordPress is happy.

**As a result, none of the concerns you need to worry about are related to WordPress.**

Your only concerns should be:

- The dev ops process of installing the new version
- Backing up the database and restoring it if things go wrong

Is it advisable though? I'd say so if it gives you improved security, but that is not a WordPress question, it's a MariaDB question.

> Is there a performance advantage for upgrading centos 7 mariadb 5.5 to centos 8 mariadb 10.3 for wordpress?

There might be, but that's not a WordPress question, that's a MariaDB question. I would be very surprised to see a performance loss that is statistically meaningful. You should ask on ServerFault.

> Or I should stick to centos 7 mariadb 5.5 to avoid unnecessary trouble?

That's entirely up to you, and a matter of opinion. There is no canonical factual answer to this. You will need to evaluate how much time it will take to do the changes, and weigh up wether it's worth the time. Different people will give different answers.